# How to do this manually. How to get the output for the 3rd, 5th, & 7th call to Print_Array?

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define SIZE 10
    void Print_Array(int values[], int length);
    void swap(int values[], int i, int j);
    void Move_Max(int values[], int max_index);
    void Simple_Sort(int values[], int length);

    int main() {
```

How do I use these numbers?
Is SIZE & length one and the same thing?

```
        int my_vals[SIZE] = {83, 89, 94, 73, 11, 33, 25, 34, 73, 41};

        Print_Array(my_vals, SIZE); //<- FIRST CALL TO PRINT

        Simple_Sort(my_vals, SIZE);


        system("PAUSE");
    }

    void Simple_Sort(int values[], int length) {
        int i;
```

So here length would be 10?
I am starting from the end of my_vals? So would I be starting at 73? Since it's 10-1 = 9? So the 9th would be 73?

```
        for (i = length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            Move_Max(values, i);
            Print_Array(values, SIZE);
        }
    }

    void Move_Max(int values[], int max_index) {
        int max, i, maxi;
        max = values[0];
        maxi = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= max_index; i++)
        {
            if (max < values[i])
            {
                max = values[i];
                maxi = i;
            }
        }
        swap(values, maxi, max_index);
    }

    void swap(int values[], int i, int j) {
        int temp;
        temp = values[i];
        values[i] = values[j];
        values[j] = temp;
    }

    void Print_Array(int values[], int length) {
        int i;
        for ( i = 0; i < length; i++)
            printf("%d", values[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you run it and see? Step through with a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an array, say you have declared `int` array `A[4]` so it means that an array `A` has `length` of 4 i.e. `A[0]` to `A[3]`.
In your case, `my_vals` array is of 10 length i.e. `my_vals[0]` to `my_vals[9]`

`my_vals[0] = 83`

`..`

`..`

`my_vals[9] = 41`

In your for loop you are iterating from last i.e. from `my_vals[9]` i.e. 41

```
for (i = length - 1; i > 0; i--)
```

So the initial value of `i` will be 9.

But here you need to iterate till `i` = 0 i.e.

```
for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Comment: "my_vals array is of 10 bytes length". That's not technically correct. "bytes" is the wrong word to use here. A byte is 8 bits which is not the size of an `int`.